# how to have ember 3.4 component properties combining 'computed' and 'on()'

Tags: ember.js

We have code in our ember 2.9.0 project which has Components with properties like this:

```
hide: on("init", computed("hasEnoughData", function () {
    return !this.hasEnoughData;
})),
```

When I migrate it to ember 3.4, it breaks with this error:

```
Assertion Failed: on expects function as last argument
```

Basically, the `on()` function expects the last param to be a function. This code used to work with 2.9 to combine both `computed` and `on()`.

Is there a recommended way to do this with ember 3.4?

Comment: Do you know why those are tied to init at all? Can you just make them normal computed properties? The on init seems like it may be unnecessary

Comment: That property is tied to a '.hide' css class adding. We want it to remain hidden until the 'init' has finished. Hence the dependancy on the init event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of dependence on the init hook is sometimes needed when there’s a lot of other code running in init. Here’s how I would do it, though there may be other ways. Code sample is Ember 3.x.

```
init() {
   this._super(...arguments)
   // some processing code that takes time
   this.set(‘shouldShowElement’, true)
},
hide: computed("hasEnoughData", “shouldShowElement”, function () {
    return !this.hasEnoughData && !shouldShowElement;
})),
```

Comment: Hey @handlebears, thanks for your answer. Looks like definitely a possible solution. But with this solution, I have to introduce a new variable called `shouldShowElement` which is not ideal and if i can avoid it it would be better. Is there no other way with ember 3.4 to do this? It is something which used to work fine in ember 2.9. Thanks.

Comment: What if you access `this.hide` in the init method, would that work?

Comment: I’m also wondering if tacking '.on(‘init’)` at the end of a CP is valid

Comment: Approving this answer. Thanks @handlebears I think thats the best answer (also only answer) I have received!

Comment: @edster you might check out the ember Discord chat or forums if you are still looking for more options https://www.emberjs.com/community/ very few people there end up doing SO Q&A so you could get new insights